# Long exact sequence of orbifold homotopy groups for orbifold fibration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I am looking for a reference for long exact sequence of orbifold homotopy groups of an orbifold fibration. There is a paper by W. Chen in the arXiv arXiv:math/0102020. But it is for a very general context of orbispaces which I could not quite follow.Is there anything in the literature for orbifolds in the sense of Thurston?